# F# support for latest asp.net 5 and MVC6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to find a way of building rest services in F# using the latest asp.net 5 and mvc 6 web api. Is there any direct support for this in Visual Studio 2015 as a project template? If not, could someone please put me on the right track on how to proceed? One option could be to build an F# library and then call it from a C# asp.net mvc 6 project. However I would be very interested in building a native F# mvc 6 web api. Thanks!

Google returned the following project: https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharp-dnx

The HelloFSharp sample works fine, however could not manage to make the HelloMVC project build:

- dnu restore complains about many not found dependencies
- dnx web has the following error:

  ```
  System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogValues' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
  ```

Comment: dnu/dnx are no longer a thing, the core CLR has moved to a new cli, see here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringTheNewNETDotnetCommandLineInterfaceCLI.aspx

Answer (score 1):

F# is now supported by .net core. As of this writing, F# code can only be compiled with .net core 1.0.3 LTS. On Ubuntu 16.10, use the steps described [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) to add the .net core repo.

- Make sure to install .net core 1.0.3 LTS (and not the latest .net core 1.1): `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003156`
- Create a directory for your F# project: `mkdir helloworldfsharp` and `cd helloworldfsharp`
- In that directory: `dotnet new -l f#`. This will create a new F# project
- `dotnet restore`. This will restore all packages and install the F# compiler.
- `dotnet build`
- `dotnet run`

**Edit**: The previous steps generates a console application. If you want to create a asp.net core mvc app, adapt the generated files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275408/asp-net-core-1-0-f-project) (as you see in the link, this is quite straightforward).