# How to access static classes in a .net asp.core library from f#

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#

I'm trying to translate the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace AspNetCoreDotNetCore2App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

to f#

I've come up with this:

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

type Program =     
    static member BuildWebHost =
        fun (args : string []) ->
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build()

    static member Main(args : string []) =    
        BuildWebHost(args).Run()
```

but get an error when building:

```
D:\documents\code\rhea\Program.fs(318,13): error FS0039: The value, namespace, type or module 'WebHost' is not defined.
 Maybe you want one of the following:   IWebHost   WebHostBuilder   WebHostDefaults   WebHostExtensions   Web
D:\documents\code\rhea\Program.fs(323,9): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'BuildWebHost' is not defined. Maybe y
ou want one of the following:   Builder   IWebHost
```

Here's the documentation of WebHost:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll in your .fsproj file? If you do but it has conditions on it, are those conditions met? The most common problem I've seen is a TargetFramework of v4.0 when the DLL conditions are TargetFramework of v4.5 or above, so although you think the DLL is referenced, it isn't actually referenced yet until you change your project's TargetFramework.

Comment: Also, that's not how you declare program entry point in F#.

Comment: I recommend modifying one of the F# templates from the .NET SDK. “dotnet new webapi -lang F#” and go from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 1.0 F# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275408/asp-net-core-1-0-f-project)

Answer (score 1):

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

let createWebHostBuilder args =
   WebHost
       .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>();

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()
    0
```